# Twitter API - Obtain user tweets and parse into a table/database

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

This is a small project I'd like to get started on in the near future. It's still in the planning stage so this post is more about being **steered in the right direction**

Essentially, I'd like to obtain tweets from a user and parse the tweets into a table/database, with the aim to be able to run this program in real-time.

My initial plan to tackle this was to use `Beautiful Soup`, a Python specific library, however, I believe the Twitter API is the better approach (advice on this subject would be appreciated)

There are still 3 unknowns:

1. Where do I store the tweets once obtained?
2. How to parse the tweets?
3. Where to store the parsed data?

To answer (3), I suppose it depends on what I want to do with the data. I still haven't decided how I'll use the parsed data but I know that I'd like it put into categories so my thinking is probably a database/table/excel??

A few questions still to answer and I'd like you guys to steer me in the right direction. My programming language knowledge is limited to just C for now, but as this project means a great deal to me, I'm willing to put the effort in and learn the necessary languages/APIs.

What languages/APIs will I need to gain an understanding of to accomplish this project? From where I stand, it seems to be Twitter API and Python.

EDIT: So I have a basic script going which obtains a user tweets. It works better than expected. However, I'd like to take it another step. I'd like to only obtain the users' tweets if it contains a hashtag inside of the tweet. All other tweets should be ignored. How best to do this?

Here is a snippet of the basic code I have going:

```
import tweepy
import twitter_credentials

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_KEY, twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

stuff = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'XXXXXXXXXX', count = 10, include_rts = False)

for status in stuff:
    print(status.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scraping Twitter (or any other social network) with for example Beautiful soup, as you said, is not a good idea for 2 reasons :

- if the source pages changes (name attributes, div ids...), you have to keep your code up to date
- your script can be banned because scraping is not "allowed".

To answer your questions :

1) you can store the tweets wherever you want : csv, mysql, sqlite, redis, neo4j...

2) With official API, you get JSON. Here is a Tweet Object : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html . With tweepy, for example `status.text` will give you the text of the tweet.

3) Same as #1. If you don't know actually what you will do with the data, store the full JSONs. You will be able later to parse them.

I suggest tweepy/python (http://www.tweepy.org/) or twit/nodejs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit). And read official docs : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index